# Set default title by content type in Panelizer

Tags: panels

Is there a way to set a default title per content type using Panelizer?  I see that you can use substitutions and change the title after you've created the content, but I would like it to use a specific substitution by default.

I know that I could use the autonode titles module, but I'd rather not add on more modules.  Any ideas?
-JB

EDIT:
Just to clarify, I want to use a substitution for the title (a field from the content type), and the reason I want to set the default is so my admins don't need to change it themselves.

Comment: do you like use custom idea in your custom module with some line code only?

Comment: Are you suggesting I edit the existing module?  That would be fine with me if you give me a clue where the necessary line in the code is...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a custom module already and you want to 'set' the title prior to saving the node then you can use [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7).

To avoid contributor confusion when creating the node you can also do a form_alter and set the #access of the title field to false.  This will hide the field from the contributor.